# Fill each datagridview from each tabpages clone in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, tabcontrol

I have a clone tabpage which has a datagridview.
I tired to fill datagridview in each tabpage , because it's only fill on tabpage1

This is my code for cloning tab with button:

```
Private Sub NewTab_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewTab.Click
    Dim Frm As New NewTabPage
    Dim MoreTabs As TabPage = Frm.TabPage1
    Dim i As Integer ' = 1
    For i = 1 To TabControl1.TabPages.Count
        MoreTabs.Text = "TabPage" & i + 1
    Next i
    TabControl1.Controls.Add(MoreTabs)
    Frm.Dispose()
End Sub
```

This is my code for fill datagridview with backgroundworker :

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FPathTab + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & CSheetTab1 & "]'", MyConnection)
    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    DtSet.Clear()
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
End Sub
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Me.TabControl1.TabPages(TabControl1.SelectedIndex).Text = Trim("Asset" & CTabName & " 20" & CTabName1)
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
    dv = DtSet.Tables(0).DefaultView
End Sub
```

Please Help, how to fill datagridview with different data for each tabpages ?

Comment: reread your question as somebody who might see this question, and think, what is missing here to make it a useful question? I don't have a clue what your problem is, what you are intending to do, nor do we know how you call the backgroundworker. Also your naming in the NewTab_Click is not very readable.

Comment: in this point, i don't know to fill datagridview on other tabpages.